Cookie temperatures in commercial convection oven
We recently started baking our cookies in a commercial convection oven, moving from a home convection oven.  We like our cookies to be a little gooey on the inside and we are able to achieve this pretty easily with the home oven.  We also aim for an internal temperature of 175F.  In the home oven, we bake at a temperature of 325F.
The first pass in the commercial oven, the cookies were way overcooked after just a fraction of the time.  The also rose a little more than in the home oven, were more browned.  In the home oven, they would usually settle a little after they were removed from the oven and allowed to cool.  That is not happening in the commercial oven.  The cookies are definitely a little more on the "cakey" side.  We've tried lowering the oven temperature of commercial oven to 300F with a high fan, and the cookies come out okay, but not perfect, and there is a very small window to get them at the right temperature.
Are there any other tips?  Should we reduce the temperature a little more?  We're going into the kitchen again for another pass at perfection, and I'm trying to formulate a game plan, so any advice would be appreciated.

Have you measured the oven temperatures with a separate thermometer? Are you using the same type of baking sheets?

The first batch we didn't and it turns out that the ovens were running a little hot.  The next batches I measured the oven and adjusted the temperatiures.

Pretty much a duplicate? Not voting that way as perhaps not exactly, but certainly in the same line. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/71609/34242
